# Read excel file extension from struts control <s:file>

Tags: java, struts2, apache-poi

I want read contents of excel file selected using 
. I am using POI 3.8. The problem is I am not able to identify
if this file is xls or xlsx. Please help

Comment: Why not? Check the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to know?

Just use [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) to load the excel file, and it'll autodetect for you. You then don't need to know, and your code remains completely generic between the two file formats.